# When will Google Chrome support access to audio (in HTML 5) on Windows?

Tags: audio, google-chrome, html5-audio

My understanding is that Chrome 11  supports access to  getUserMedia for HTML5 native audio and video stream on the Android but possibly not on MS Windows or (I think) Mac, or iOS.

Anyone know when support for Windows is planned?
Support for iOS?
Support for the Mac O/S ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is planned for early 2012, according to http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/24/chrome-getting-native-gamepad-webcam-and-webrtc-support-in-early-2012/

It seems that the code for this is only just now landing in Chromium though, so it might take a little longer for it to show up outside of Chrome Dev builds.